# I am trying to call a function inside the same function that has been defined

Tags: python, python-3.5

I am trying to do this:

```
def enter():
    print("hi")
    enter()
```

However, it gives me this, at first:

```
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
```

However, after that stream of data it starts to give me errors like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
    enter()
  File "C:/Users/offcampus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/len finder.py", line 11, in enter
```

It says recursion error that I have reached the maximum depth, could someone tell me how to fix this.

Also, it would be appreciated if someone told me what recursion error even means.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Why are you "trying to do this..."? What you write gives you exactly what you have, which is an infinite recursion. When a function calls another, it has to push the current return address onto the stack. Calling itself infinitely overflows the stack (you run out of stack memory). What are you really wanting to do?

Comment: A stack overflow on stackoverflow :-D

Comment: @lurker, I am just doing this for fun, I was experimenting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling a function inside itself is known as recursion, and is an alternative to a loop. But it comes at a price. Python needs to "remember" all previous calls to the function, as opposed to loops that reset every time. Because of this, you can understand why eventually your computer would run out of memory, because you don't *stop* calling `enter`.

This is called a Stack Overflow -- ie, when the computer's "stack" (memory) overflows (gets too high and kinda falls over). Other older languages, such as C, don't handle this well **at all** and stack overflows kinda became a thing for programmers to deal with, (which is why this is called StackOverflow.com -- to help others with their issues).

To avoid this, Python sets a limit to how far you can recurse, and passing this limit will raise an error (instead of breaking your computer). To prevent your code from hitting this (very high) limit, you need to specify an *exit condition*. This is where you *return* instead of recursing again. This can be as simple as an if statement, or more complicated. It also makes sense. The way you have it now, it's obvious why it keeps recursing, **you never tell it not to.**